# Is there any way to use multiple source tables in FROM clause without using JOIN in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can implement one nested SELECT statement in the FROM clause like this and it works:

```
SELECT [table1].[ID] as [table_1_ID]
FROM
(SELECT [ID] FROM  [the_table_1] WHERE [address] like 'street5' ) as [table1]
```

Ideally, I wish to add multiple similar nested SELECT statement inside the FROM clause without using join, to end up something like this (the following code obviously doesn't work)

```
 SELECT [nested_selects].[table1].[ID]  as [table_1_ID],
        [nested_selects].[table2].[ID]  as [table_2_ID]
    FROM (
    (SELECT [ID] FROM  [the_table_1] WHERE [address] like 'street5' ) as [table1],
    (SELECT [ID] FROM  [the_table_2] WHERE [address] like 'street5' ) as [table2]
    ) as [nested_selects]
```

(From each source table I need only one single value. WHERE clause does that.)

I know how to do it with JOIN, but for some reason I wish to do it **without** JOIN.
Is such a thing possible in SQL Server?

Comment: It's a style that's been **discouraged** to be used since 1992 when the SQL-92 standard was published - don't start using it - do use **proper ANSI/ISO** `JOIN`s !

Comment: @marc_s Thank you. You mean using stored procedures? Then might it be possible to do that?
I know it's not a good approach, it's just a test for one particular application. Actually to compare the query time with the JOIN method.

Comment: What you have there is still a `JOIN`, it's called a `CROSS JOIN`. But you then seem to think that you can reference inside the subquery using 3 part naming. `[nested_selects].[table1].[ID]` would *not* reference the column `ID` in the inner subquery `table` inside the outer subquery `nested_selects`; It would try to reference the column `ID` in the object `table1` (which doesn't exist in the context of that part of the query) in the **schema** `nested_selects`. This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: *And, just to mention that using 3 part naming to reference a column is due to be deprecated in SQL Server.*

Comment: @marc_s In fact that 3 part naming approach was just to clarify my question. I know it doesn't work and I don't mind about solving it this way. My question is simple if there is "any" way to solve it without JOIN.

Comment: No - if you're "combining" tables in any way, you are **joining** them - just depends on the style of the syntax you're using to express this - stick with the proper, explicit `JOIN` rather than messy, old, discouraged other ways.....

Comment: Thank you.
My idea was that since my query result is just one row (one single value from each table) and since JOIN matches all my big tables' rows based on my chosen key, there might be any chance that picking my single desirable values from each table (using WHERE condition) can be faster in processing time. Because matching all other rows based on KEY is not useful for me.

Comment: For some scenarios, you can use `CROSS APPLY` on individually selected rows to get roughly the same effect as regular joins would. However, depending on the query this can be far less efficient than doing proper joins. People often think  "joins are slow" when the real issue is that the engine doesn't know how to perform the join efficiently due to missing (unique) indexes, out of date statistics or a skewed distribution of data. Solving those problems properly pays dividends much more than going out of your way to second-guess the engine.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you. I didn't know that speed of JOIN query is dependent on the structure of the data. However, the reply from "allmhuran" solved my problem for now. For usual tasks I will stick to the normal `join` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that only a single value will be returned from the subqueries, you can nest the selects inside the select. You don't need a `from` at all (I have replaced your `like` with `=`):

```
select
   table_1_id = (SELECT [ID] FROM  [the_table_1] WHERE [address] = 'street5' ),
   table_2_id = (SELECT [ID] FROM  [the_table_2] WHERE [address] = 'street5' );
```

You don't technically *have* to enforce this guarantee. But if you happen to get more than one row back for a subquery in the select, SQL with throw a `Subquery returned more than 1 value` error. So, either put a unique constraint on `address`, or add something to each sub-select that guarantees only one row is returned.

Comment: Thank you. It answered my question. 
For avoiding "more than 1 value" issue I just added DISTINCT and it works. `SELECT DISTINCT [ID] FROM [the_table...`

Comment: That doesn't guarantee a single value result. There could be more than one distinct ID value for a given address: `create table t(id int, address varchar(20); insert t values (1, 'street5'), (2, 'street5'); select distinct ID from t where address = 'street5';` You can guarantee a single row with operators like `top 1`, or aggregate functions like `min()` or `max()`, or by putting a unique constraint on `address` in both tables, and always searching based on equality (not `like`)

Comment: I understand your point. Here "address" is a fake name. In my data, it can rarely be not unique. For me it's enough if I prevent error by `distinct`. I think it does prevent error. Doesn't it?

Comment: Nope, distinct won't help you. If it's possible to return more than one `ID` value for a given `address` argument, then you need to decide how to handle that. Do you pick one at "random"? If it can ever happen, you can't assume you will get a single row back. You either have to strictly enforce it, or write the application in such a way that it can handle multiple rows being returned (ie, go back to using `from`)

Comment: Yeah, a random row/value would be fine. Then I can also write `SELECT top(1) [ID] FROM [the_table...]`. I tried it and it works.